# How do you install stacks and packages in diamondback?

Tags: ros, stacks, ros-diamondback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have diamondback installed on Ubuntu 10.10.

How do I go about installing other stacks (for instance, the rosjava_core, camera_umd (or more specifically, I'd like the uvc_cam2 package so I can do streaming webcam video), etc.

Everything I find online shows how to do it with cturtle and those instructions don't work (usually something about rosinstall, which doesn't seem to exist in diamondback), and trying things like "sudo apt-get install ros-diamondback-rosjava (or -rosjava_core or -rosjava-core)" all come back with "Unable to locate package: _______"

Getting very frustrated here! Help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11080/how-do-you-install-stacks-and-packages-in-diamondback?/) by [mkopack](https://answers.ros.org/users/1024/mkopack/) on ROS Answers with karma: 171 on 2011-08-31

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See the [rosinstall Installation](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosinstall#Installation) page for how to install rosinstall. Note that rosinstall does not come in Diamondback, it is available separately.

After you have `rosinstall` installed, you should be able to follow any package/stack installation instructions that use rosinstall.

To note, many packages and stacks are not released as .debs, which is the reason you are unable to do `sudo apt-get install ros-diamondback-...`. If you get that "Unable to locate package:..." error when attempting to install a stack, that's the most likely reason for it.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2011-08-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For the uvc_cam2 `sudo apt-get install ros-diamondback-freiburg-tools` should work.

In general, when you find the wiki page for a page, look what stack it is in and install ros-diamondback(or other release)-STACKNAME. If that package doesn't exist there are probably no binaries.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-08-31

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1